# Why would 1 navigation property be NULL?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have a simple query that is returning NULL in a navigation properties for just one of the results. I could understand if they were all NULL, it would mean I need to force the lazy loading to include them, but only 1 of 7 results is coming back NULL.

```
var employees = this.Roles.Select(r => r.Employee).ToList();
```

"this" is a Team; Roles is a many-to-many between Employees and Teams. This seems straight-forward, but one of the 7 results is NULL; the rest are valid Employee entities.

There is no meaningful difference between any of the 7 rows in the Roles table, nor the 7 Employees rows in the database. What sort of thing could cause 1 of the Employees to fail to retrieve?

The only thing I could think of is if there were some sort of caching happening; if the employee that was NULL was created after the others; and I'm seeing a result that doesn't have that employee's data. But caching doesn't seem like a real possibility; the same result is happening on multiple servers.

Comment: It isn't clear, *do* you have lazy loading enabled? If not, do you have `Employee` as an include in your original query? If not, are you sharing your data context with a function that might be loading employees (but not all of them)?

Comment: You're right with your last sentence... turns out 6 of the employees just happen to be getting pulled in other queries that use the same context. Thanks! But question about "do you have lazy loading enabled"... I'm not familiar with enabling or disabling this; I thought it was just something that automatically happened if you didn't specifically access the data?

Comment: There are multiple flavors of EF, so you'll need to consult the documentation on the version you're using. With the DB-first approach that we use with our application, there is a "LazyLoadingEnabled" property on the data context itself. I'm not sure if it defaults to true or false when the model is generated, although (again) the documentation will let you know.